# PieMenuStyle in qml error ReferenceError: __control is not defined, how to fix this error

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using qt 5.12, tried running an example code of PieMenuStyle and got these error.

```
file:///home/aishu/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/Style.qml:52: **ReferenceError: __control is not defined
```

leads to line

```
readonly property Item control: __control
file:///home/aishu/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/PieMenuStyle.qml:147: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null**
 leads to line  
readonly property real radius: Math.min(control.width, control.height) * 0.5
    
    file:///home/aishu/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/PieMenuStyle.qml:113: **ReferenceError: __control is not defined**
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

    Window {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        title: qsTr("Hello World")
        PieMenuStyle {
             shadowRadius: 0
    
             menuItem: Item {
                 id: item
                 rotation: -90 + sectionCenterAngle(styleData.index)
    
                 Rectangle {
                     width: parent.height * 0.2
                     height: width
                     color: "darkorange"
                     radius: width / 2
                     anchors.right: parent.right
                     anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    
                     Text {
                         id: textItem
                         text: control.menuItems[styleData.index].text
                         anchors.centerIn: parent
                         color: control.currentIndex === styleData.index ? "red" : "white"
                         rotation: -item.rotation
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PieMenuStyle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-piemenustyle.html) is used to modify the style of a [`PieMenu`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-extras-piemenu.html) but your code does not see any, so the solution is to add it and place the [`PieMenuStyle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-piemenustyle.html) as the style of the [`PieMenu`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-extras-piemenu.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    PieMenu {
        id: pieMenu
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        MenuItem {
            text: "Action 1"
            onTriggered: print("Action 1")
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Action 2"
            onTriggered: print("Action 2")
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Action 3"
            onTriggered: print("Action 3")
        }

        style: PieMenuStyle {
            shadowRadius: 0

            menuItem: Item {
                id: item

                rotation: -90 + sectionCenterAngle(styleData.index)

                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.height * 0.2
                    height: width
                    color: "darkorange"
                    radius: width / 2
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                    Text {
                        id: textItem

                        text: control.menuItems[styleData.index].text
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        color: control.currentIndex === styleData.index ? "red" : "white"
                        rotation: -item.rotation
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: pieMenu.popup(0, 0)
}
```